# Spray JSON root object reader as array or object

Tags: json, scala, deserialization, spray-json

I have domain model like:

```
sealed trait MyTrait
case class MyObject(a: String) extends MyTrait
case class MyArray(a: Seq(MyObject)) extends MyTrait
```

Example usages would look like:

```
// array
[{"a": "foo"}, {"a": "bar"}]
//object
{"a": "foobar"}
```

I want to write one Spray JSON reader for MyTrait like:

```
implicit val myTraitReader: RooJsonReader[MyTrait] = new RootJsonReader[MyTrait] {
  override def read(json: JsValue): MyTrait = {
    // MAGIC?
    // I need to be able to distinguish between JsObject and JsArray
    // If I do json.asJsObject this is a JsObject then :D
    // there is not json.asJsArray?
    // How to pattern match on this use case?
  }
}
```

All questions are commented out. :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like below?

```
implicit val myTraitReader: RootJsonReader[MyTrait] = new RootJsonReader[MyTrait] {
    import MyObjectProtocol._
    import MyArrayProtocol._
    override def read(json: JsValue): MyTrait = json match {
      case jsObj: JsObject => ??? // Convert to MyObject here
      case jsArr: JsArray => ??? // Convert to MyArray here
      case _ => ??? // A JsNull here??
    }
  }
```